# Inserting value into sorted array without duplicates: C++

Tags: c++, arrays, duplicates, insertion-sort

For this program I have three data files. The first has a list of numbers, the second is a list of numbers with an add (A) or delete (D) command. I have to put the numbers from the first file into the third file, then update the final file based on the commands and numbers in the second file. The third file cant have duplicates and must be sorted while values are being inserted. Here are the functions I have, I'm having difficulty getting the items stored into the array without duplicates. The array must be statically sized, I did a #define of max size 2000 which is more than enough to handle the numbers I need. Thanks so much! If I should upload the main let me know, but I'm fairly certain the problem lies in one of these functions.

```
int search(int value, int list[], int n)        // returns index, n is logical size of array
{
    int index = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(value == list[i])
        {
            index = i;
            return index;
        }
}

return index;
}

void storeValue(int value, int list[], int& n)
{
    int i = n;
    for(; i > 0 && list[i - 1] < value; i--)
    {
        list[i] = list[i - 1];
    }
    list[i] = value;
    n++;
}

void deleteValue(int loc, int list[], int n)
{
    if(loc >= 0 && loc < n)
    {
        for(int i = loc; i < n - 1; i++)
            list[i] = list[i +1];
        n--;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Now duplicates are being stored, but only for some numbers.
For example: my 3rd file is: 1,2,8,8,9,101,101,104,etc. 
The output should be: 1,2,8,9,101,104,etc
value: value to be inserted
list[]: array being modified (must be static)
n: logical size of array
I can't figure out why some numbers are duplicated and others aren't
In my main, I run the search function and if a -1 is returned (the value isn't already found) then I run the storeValue function.

Here are my updated functions:

```
int search(int value, int list[], int n)        // returns index
{
    int index = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(value == list[i])
        {
            index = i;
            return index;
        }
    }

    return index;
}    

void storeValue(int value, int list[], int& n)
{
    int i = n;
    for(; i > 0 && list[i - 1] > value; i--)
    {
        list[i] = list[i - 1];
    }
    list[i] = value;
    n++;
}

void deleteValue(int loc, int list[], int& n)
{
   if(loc >= 0 && loc < n)
   {
        for(int i = loc; i < n; i++)
        { 
            if (i == loc)
            {
               list[i] = list[i + 1];
               i++; 
            }
        }
        n--;
   }

}
```

Comment: Do you need to use an array?  There are other structures that handle unique elements, such as `std::map` and `std::set`.

Comment: Yes, I do need to use an array that's statically sized.

Answer (score 0):

In your deleteValue function, you are deleting the value, but will end up with a duplicate because you are just reassigning the current index to the next value. For example, if you have the array:

```
char array[3] = [1, 2, 3];
```

and you wanted to delete the second integer, your function currently would output this:

```
[1, 3, 3]
```

What you want to do is make a new array and loop through your entire list, making sure to leave out the last element like so:

```
char* deleteValue(int loc, int list[], int n)
{
    char* newArray[n - 1];
    if (loc >= 0 && loc < n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            if (i == loc) // You have arrived at the element that needs to be deleted
            {
                 newArray[i] = list[i + 1];
                 i++; // So we skip over the deleted element
            }
            else
                 newArray[i] = list[i];
        }
     }
    return newArray;
}
```

And this should take care of the case where the last value is duplicated.

Comment: Why did you use a char type on the function? I'm confused about that. Also, for some reason my storeValue function stores everything in reverse order but I can't quite figure out where it goes wrong.

Comment: I fixed the reverse order problem, I had a < and > mixed up. Now it looks like values aren't being stored that should be.